# Refreshing a question doesn't update the answer count properly

Tags: bug, android-app, answer-count

In the Stack Exchange Android App <strike>v1.0.7</strike> 1.0.33 (with a HTC One running Android 4.4.2), the answer count for a question you're viewing is displayed in two places:

- In the label of the answer tab: 
  [image: "0 answers"]
- At the bottom of the question tab:
  [image: "view 0 answers"]

I've noticed that these counts don't reliably update when new answers arrive.

- If you refresh the question tab, neither count updates.
- If you refresh the answer tab, the *second* count will be updated, but the answer tab's count will not, leaving the two out of sync.

Refreshing either tab should probably update both counts!

---

Screenshots of the bug in action:

1. [This question had 0 answers earlier when I opened it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okkOb.png) I waited for it to be answered.
2. A while later, the question now has an answer. [After refreshing the question tab, though, there's no signs of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVFF3.png)
3. [Switching to the answer tab, it's empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRV9B.png)
4. [After refreshing - there's the answer!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rva7.png) The tab still says 0 answers though.
5. Switching back to the question tab, [the bottom button now acknowledges the new answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43X8F.png), but the tab count still doesn't.

Comment: Just my speculation, but it seems that the refresh only applies to each tab (which is a `Fragment`), not the whole `Activity` itself. Also, I guess each tab's state will be saved when it's opened for the first time, possibly to save resource usage. While it seems this is working as designed, the only bug is "answer tab's count is not updated after refreshing either tab". On the other hand, maybe a full refresh (activity, question tab, and answer tab) can be suggested. This bug still needs to be fixed though. +1